# how to convert conotur co-ordinates to complex format(x+y*j0)

Tags: python, image-processing, contour

contour finding of segmented image of circle results in contour which is not circular along with boundary contour, contour finding is done using this:

contours = skimg.measure.find_contours(edges,0.8)

how to convert these coordinates into complex format.

Comment: this `measure.find_contours` will return to you Cartesian coordinates, as list, you mean you want polar coordinates ? why complex number ?

Comment: could u convert these co-ordinates to complex form..

Comment: but I don't understand why complex number ? what it mean ? in a 2D image each point is define by coordinates (Cartesian or Polar). Can you explain the context ?

Comment: to find fourier descriptor we need to convert co-ordinates to complex plane...

Answer (score 0):

what I have found about Fourier descriptors :

http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/fd/node1.html

`skimg.measure.find_contours` return a list of array with coordinates `[x, y]`, so you already have your coordinate because you will use it in the complex form as :

`x+y*i`

After depends how you will use it in your next calculus, but, for example, if you want to read all the `y` values :

```
for i in range(len(contours)):
    for j in range(len(contours[i])):
        print contours[i][j][1]
```

you can also use `cmath` to handle complex number:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html

you can also use `complex` :

```
>>> x=4.90
>>> y=7.890
>>> CoordComplex=complex(x,y)
>>> CoordComplex
(4.9+7.89j)
```

or to creat a list of complex from list of arrays :

```
compCoord=[]
for i in range(len(contours)):
    for j in range(len(contours[i])):
        compCoord.append(complex(contours[i][j][0], contours[i][j])[1])
```